# How to correctly handle simplified model in Fluent/Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

Let's assume, I have a `User` model and this model contains `products` children (one to many relation).

In some situations, in my iOS app, I need only to display list with all users so I don't need to query my database about products.

How to preform, in the easiest way, fetching users without its children in Fluent?
Do I need to create a separate model that doesn't contain products?

```
func getAllUsersHandler(_ request: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<[User]> {
    User.query(on: request.db).all()
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. By default doing `User.query(on: req.db).all()` with not return any children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default situation is that a query on the `User` model will not include any `Children` fields in the result. To include them, you need `.with(\.$products)` in the query.

You can limit the fields returned by modifying your query as in the example:

```swift
User.query(on: request.db).field(\.$name).field(\.$email).all()
```

This only brings those fields into the model and leaves unwanted fields in an uninitialised state. See [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/query/#field) for more information.